# .NET MVC 4 Membership.CreateUser() Security Exception Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am getting the following error at this line of code...

```
MembershipUser newuser = Membership.CreateUser(usersvm.username, usersvm.password,
                usersvm.email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);
```

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To        grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> [SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  To create the source, you need permission to read all event logs to make sure that the new source name is unique.  Inaccessible logs: Security.]

I also have this in the web.config file

```
  <system.web>
     <trust level="Full"/>
```

Here is some stack trace

```
MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.WriteToEventLog(Exception e, String action) +380
System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status) +207
System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, MembershipCreateStatus& status) +26
```

Comment: Which Membership provider are you using?

Comment: MySqlMembershipProvider ... will amend the question

Comment: Under what conditions does this happen?  Locally on the development server?  Or On your hosting provider?  What version of IIS?  What version of the MySql data provider?

Comment: Hi, this is on localhost, although I pushed to appharbor and it does the same thing, MySQL data provider is 6.5.4 ... I might have a clue that this is related to security logs?  http://forums.asp.net/t/1492041.aspx/1  Still researching... thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like the worker process does not have rights to write to the event log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add this writeExceptionsToEventLog = "false" in web.config like this

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
      <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider"/>
           <add autogenerateschema="true" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" ....
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that.  This is why providing more information is helpful.